# error from register: TypeError: res is undefined/ SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typeerror, mern

How do I get rid of these two console errors?

I'm creating a marketplace application using react/mern. My current issue is that whenever I try to sign up or sign in a user I'm constantly getting these two errors "**error from register:  TypeError: res is undefined/ SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**".

I have tried everything, looked at every stackoverflow question there is and nothing is working. When I look at the network console response in dev tools it says that the sign-up/sign-in has been successful yet nothing is going into my database and I'm constantly getting these two console errors.

**Register.js** (The errors specifically reference the handleSubmitReg function)

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Spinner, Alert, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { registerUser } from '../functions/userData';
import '../components/register.scss';
import React from 'react'

function Register() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [alertShow, setAlertShow] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const[userData, setUserData] = useState({
    name: null,
    email: "",
    university: "",
    password: "",
    repeatPassword: ""
  });

  const handleChanges = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUserData({ ...userData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }

  const handleSubmitRegistration= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    registerUser(userData)

    .then(res => {
        if (!res.error) {
            window.location.replace('/auth/login')
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
            setError(res.error);
            setAlertShow(true);
        }
    }).catch(err => console.error('error from register: ', err))
}

return (
  <>
  <div className="register">
  <Card>
                <Card.Body>
    <h1 className="auth-heading">Sign Up!</h1>
    <Form className="col-lg-8" onSubmit={handleSubmitRegistration}>
    {alertShow &&
                        <Alert variant="danger" onClose={() => setAlertShow(false)} dismissible>
                            <p>
                                {error}
                            </p>
                        </Alert>
                    }
                  
                        <Form.Group controlId="forName" className="col-lg-8">
                            <Form.Label>Name *</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" name="name" placeholder="Student123 or Stud Student" onChange={handleChanges} required />
                            <Form.Text muted>
                                The name can be your real one or a username.
                            </Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>
                      
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" className="col-lg-12">
                            <Form.Label>Email address *</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" name="email" placeholder="student@gmail.com" onChange={handleChanges} required />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="forUniversity" className="col-lg-12">
                            <Form.Label>University/Institution *</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" name="university" placeholder="Monash University" onChange={handleChanges} required />
                        </Form.Group>
                    
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword" className="col-lg-6">
                            <Form.Label>Password *</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={handleChanges} required />
                            <Form.Text muted>
                                Your password must be 8-20 characters long
                            </Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group className="col-lg-6">
                            <Form.Label>Repeat Password *</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" name="repeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat password" onChange={handleChanges} required />
                        </Form.Group>
                    
                    {loading ?
                        <Button className="col-lg-12 btnAuth" variant="dark" disabled >
                            Please wait... <Spinner animation="border" />
                        </Button>
                        :
                        <Button variant="dark" className="col-lg-12 btnAuth" value="Add to DB" type="submit">Sign Up</Button>
                    }

                    <p className="bottom-msg-paragraph">Already have an account? <Link to="/auth/login">Sign In</Link>!</p>
      </Form>
 </Card.Body>
 </Card>
  </div>
  
  
  </>
)

}
export default Register;
```

**userData.js**

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

export async function registerUser(userData) {
 
    return (await fetch(`${baseUrl}/auth/register`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({userData})
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((userData) => {
        console.log('Success:', userData);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    }
 ))
}

export async function loginUser(userData) {
    return (await fetch(`/auth/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify(userData)
    })).json();
}
```

Comment: "When I look at the network console response in dev tools it says that the sign-up/sign-in has been successful" Are You sure the response returns HTTP 200? It seems like the server is returning content that is not a JSON object. There is a chance that it is an HTTP 500  page.

Comment: Hi Matthew, 
Yes it is returning a HTTP 200 status. This is a reason I'm getting really confused because the network tells me it's working but it's not...

Comment: Can you take a look at the response tab in the network panel? This should show you what is actually returned in the response.

Comment: The response is 'Sign up successful' for sign up and 'Login successful' for login

Comment: So it is `Sign up successful`, not `{ message: "Sign up successful" }` or something similar? If it is the former, then the response itself is not a JSON. but a simple string. Obviously, it won't work when you do `response.json()`, instead, do `response.text()`

Comment: I did change it to response.text() and it made no difference...

Answer (score 0):

Your `registerUser` function doesn't return any value and only `console.log` it. So fix it like this

```
export async function registerUser(userData) {
    return (await fetch(`${baseUrl}/auth/register`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                userData
            })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json()) // *** Returns Results
        .catch((error) => error)) // *** Returns Error
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion this prevents me from getting the errors but it still doesn't pass any data to my database or show me anything in my network console in devtools. It's almost like it just deletes the data I input if that makes sense?

Comment: If you're not getting any errors from database then there might be a problem with your database connection. If it's possible add `/auth/register` module code to the first post

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a noob, I don't understand how I can do that. Any suggestions? How do I import it or require it in module code?

Comment: No problem at all. Just copy and paste part of your code that handles `/auth/register` endpoint